# .blur() does not trigger when clicking outside datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, onblur

I have a `.blur()` event for four text inputs, that has datepicker and timepicker attached to them. When i "tab" to the next control, it works fine, but when i click somewhere outside, the event does not trigger. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a problem with the `.blur()` event?

JavasSript code for the event:

```
    $(".calcTimespan").blur(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("CalculateTimespan")',
            data: {
                "franDatum": $("#Dyk_FranDatum").val(),
                "franTid": $("#Dyk_FranTid").val(),
                "tillDatum": $("#Dyk_TillDatum").val(),
                "tillTid": $("#Dyk_TillTid").val()
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "FAIL")
                    $("#Dyk_DyktidMinuter").val(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Ett fel inträffade vid hämtning av dykning!");
            }
        });
    });
```

The HTML:

```
    <div>
        <label for="Fr_n_datum">Fr&#229;n datum</label>
        <label style="margin-left: 40px;">Tid</label>
        <br />
        <input class="halv datumpicker calcTimespan" id="Dyk_FranDatum" name="Dyk.FranDatum" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="halv tidpicker calcTimespan" id="Dyk_FranTid" name="Dyk.FranTid" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
        <label for="Till_datum">Till datum</label>
        <label style="margin-left: 50px;">Tid</label>
        <br />
        <input class="halv datumpicker calcTimespan" id="Dyk_TillDatum" name="Dyk.TillDatum" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="halv tidpicker calcTimespan" id="Dyk_TillTid" name="Dyk.TillTid" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <br />

    <div>
        <label for="Dyktim__min_">Dyktim (min)</label>
        <label style="margin-left: 33px;">Pris per minut</label>
        <br />
        <input class="halv" id="Dyk_DyktidMinuter" name="Dyk_DyktidMinuter" type="text" value="" />
        <input class="halv" id="Dyk_Pris" name="Dyk.Pris" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
```

I'm targeting IE9 only.

**EDIT**
It seems that the events are working fine. The problem is that when I'm clicking in the datepicker to select a date, already at the mouse-down on the date, the event is triggered, even though the value is not already set by the component in the input-text!

Now, I have to find a way to either get the "mouse down"-date or delay the event to when it's actually set in the input-text.

Comment: that's not HTML.. you should insert the *generated output* of your backend code

Comment: Does the element loose focus when you click outside? The blur() event gets only called when the element looses focus.

Comment: You are right, it's updated now.

Comment: @BartFriederichs, yes, the cursor blinks in another input box.

Comment: how could you be sure that the .blur() does not trigger when clicking outside. here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/m9jEq/, i replaced the `$.ajax` by a `console.log("in")` and the "in" message is displayed every time the `input.calcTimespan` looses the focus (tested in IE9). So i think there is a problem in your ajax call.

Comment: @m.abbas You are on to something! I've added the console.log in the javascript and similar code in the controller (an incremental counter on each side). However, they are working perfectly on both sides. The problem could be when I try to set the retured value to the input-text.

Comment: Could you add an `console.log(data)` to your `success` fucntion (just before the if) and verify that you don't have any JS error in the browser console.

Comment: Please check my new "edit". It's the datepicker that causes the event to fire too soon, before the value is acually set in the input-text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was actually having was this: [jqueryUI datepicker fires input's blur before passing date, avoid/workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814292/jqueryui-datepicker-fires-inputs-blur-before-passing-date-avoid-workaround)

I used a variant of Purells answer to solve my problem.

Thanks for all support. It was the help in this question that led me to the real problem.

Comment: Good job on not selecting his answer as the real answer and in the process losing the answer for future reference. As I can no longer find it now.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be issues with IE9 and the blur event not firing consistently, try binding the elements with [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did'nt help though, same behaviour exactly.