# How to get value from text input on blur of field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to write some Javascript to get the value from two text inputs, which should be fairly straightforward.  But something is amiss.  Here is my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#fromPicker, #toPicker').datepicker({ dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd' });

        jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        jQuery('#toPicker').on('blur', function() {
            var fromDate = jQuery('#fromPicker').val();
            var toDate = jQuery('#toPicker').val();
            console.log(toDate);

            if (fromDate !== '' && toDate !== '') {
                if (isValidDate(fromDate) && isValidDate(toDate)) {
                    jQuery('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    alert('You must enter dates in the format "yyyy-mm-dd"');
                }
            } 
        });
    });

    function isValidDate(dt) {
        if (dt.match(/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I `console.log(toDate)` however, I get an empty string.  But if I do another `blur` event again (focus and unfocus the field with the data still in it), I get the correct value.  Any ideas why it doesn't work the first time?

The two text inputs have IDs of `#fromPicker` and `#toPicker` and are jQueryUI datepickers.

SOLUTION:

What ultimately did what I wanted was this:

> jQuery(function() {
>           jQuery('#fromPicker, #toPicker').datepicker({
>               dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
>           });
>
> ```
>     jQuery('#submit').on('click', function() {
>         var fromDate = jQuery('#fromPicker').val();
>         var toDate = jQuery('#toPicker').val();
>
>         if (fromDate !== '' && toDate !== '') {
>             if (isValidDate(fromDate) && isValidDate(toDate)) {
>                 // do nothing
>             } else {
>                 alert('You must enter dates in the format "yyyy-mm-dd"');
>                 return false;
>             }
>         } else {
>             return false;
>         }
>     });
> });
>
> function isValidDate(dt) {
>     if (dt.match(/^[0-9]{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/)) {
>         return true;
>     }
> } </script>
> ```

Comment: If I remove the datepicker from the inputs, the `console.log` returns the correct value each time.  So how do I get this to work with the datepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any reason for your code not to work but instead of `blur` event, try `onselect` event of the datepicker instead

```
jQuery('#toPicker').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
        // Do other stuff
    },
    // ....
);
```

Answer (score 2):

When the user clicks outside the input field (to choose a date), the input field will blur. There's no way around that. So, instead of triggering the validation on blur, use the datepicker's onSelect callback.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) { /* validation here */ }
});
```

If you want to keep your onblur-events, you could postpone validation to allow for the datepicker to fill out the field before the validation fires, like this:

```
$('#myform input').blur(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { /* validation here */ }, 1);
});
```

Using setTimeout to handle concurrency-issues may look like a hack, but due to JavaScripts single-threaded nature, it works quite nicely. John Resig of jQuery-fame talks about it in this [blogpost](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

[Link to Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814292/jqueryui-datepicker-fires-inputs-blur-before-passing-date-avoid-workaround)